# Why is ajax returning a full webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was working with ajax and wanted to find the host's ip using ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ipinfo.io',
  type: 'GET',
  data: '',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    $('#ip').html(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

Over here, ip is an empty div tag.

When i run the webpage, i get the full page from ipinfo when i want only the client's ip. Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're getting the full webpage using $.ajax - then you are storing it in the `div id=ip` ... you only want the IP, but javascript doesn't know what you want it does what you tell it to do

Comment: If you only want the IP you should request http://ipinfo.io/ip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out, add `/json` to the URL

**then make the following changes to your code**

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ipinfo.io/json', <====
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json', // <====
  data: '',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    $('#ip').html(data.ip); // <====
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the developer pages](http://ipinfo.io/developers) for ipinfo.io, they "do a bit of magic" to determine whether the page is being requested from a script, and if so, they give you a JSON response instead of an HTML response.

Apparently the heuristic they were using failed, so we want to explicitly request the JSON version. The fix for this is to change your ajax url to `http://ipinfo.io/json` instead, which will force a JSON response.

---

Then, you can get the `ip` field out of the object like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://ipinfo.io/json',
  type: 'GET',
  data: '',
  success: function(data) {
    //called when successful
    $('#ip').text(data.ip);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    //called when there is an error
    console.log(e.message);
   }
});
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zoxeuqsy/

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated my answer so that it works with the JSON response. I could have sworn I already commented this, but I don't see the comment any more (and I can't imagine why a mod would have removed it).

Answer (score 1):

Add /json to the end of the request. So call :

```
http://ipinfo.io/json
```

You could also try forcing the json as the response type.